# How to conditionally show fields in module xml?

Tags: module, xml, fields, conditional-statements

I created a simple module to enter values in textfields which I show in module positions on the frontend (banner images...).

Now I need a solution like if dropdown value in fieldname "xy" is "xyz" then show me another xml field.

Is this possible?

Comment: Adding here a link to documentation for showon attr, for future references [**Form Field - showon**](https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Showon)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Joomla's `showon` attribute in your field.

Here's an exmaple:

```
<field name="first" type="list" label="Select Something">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</field>

<field name="second" type="list" label="Select Something Else" showon="first:3">
    <option value="1">Other Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Other Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Other Option 3</option>
</field>
```

The above example will only show the second field if option **3** is selected from the first field, using `showon="first:3"`.

In the `showon` attribute, you need to define the **name** of the field and the **value**

Hope this helps

Comment: If I want to show/hide fields based module selected language it doesn't seem to work `showon="language:en-CA"` . Any solution?

Comment: @Ejaz - You're going to have to create a custom form field for that

Comment: is it compulsory to have value in numeric? as i am trying showon="fieldname:fieldvalue" and it is not working where fieldvalue is not numeric

Comment: @Rahul Kaushik I dont believe it needs to be numeric

Comment: @RahulKaushik for the purposes of translation it is sometimes preferable to use values instead of words.  For example your fieldvalue maybe in a language I do not understand but if you keep values as 0, 1, 2 that becomes less relevant, the only thing that needs to change is the label and description which can be language strings.  Alternately, if you wish to use values, you should use language strings as the values so they can be translated.  If you can imagine I am doing an output of `if ($params['field'] == "unblikenstageden" {do something}` that's a long word that I am not familiar spelling

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this excellent feature is not functional on FOF xml files (e.g. `form.form.xml`) https://pastebin.com/8Tzg5sx7  This technique should be available according to the bottom of https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Showon

Comment: Not sure as I've never used FOF. You'd have to ask the developer